# Labview historical trend timestamp

Tags: labview, dsc

I am currently working on a project in which I read some values from a MODBUS device using DSC module.

I declared 3 shared variables and enabled logging for them. I've succeeded to read the values and save them on a Citadel database correctly. The problem is when I use historical trend to show data (by assigning the start and end timestamp), it always shows the result from 1/1/1904.

Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you explain how you are publishing this data? Are you using DSC reporting server to publish or your own custom publishing mechanism.

Comment: I did not use DSC reporting server (I guess).

I should say by using max, I can view logged data. But by using historical trend (in programming panel), it always shows data from 1904.